# SignalR secure message delivery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller, signalr

So, I got a security related question.

```
// Code that was originally sent to client from the server
var hub = $.connection.hubname;        
hub.name = "UserIdFromDataBase";
```

If some malicious user will write a simple html page with the same code, will he receive all messages that will be sent the original user?

(Actually I want to organize chat between registered users that is why name/clientid should be provided by server side).

Thanks

**UPD:**

> I created a related issue at the project portal:
>   https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/432

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, but really it depends on what your server side code is doing.

SignalR will provide a unique connectionID for every connection to the hub. As long as you use the connectionID to route your messages, and not build your own routing mechanism based on values provided by the client you should be fine.

In the example you provide, when a user connects he will get a unique connectionID. Even though a second user is able to alter the values of the client side code and mimick the first user, his connectionID as provided by SignalR will be different.

Example on how to call methods on specific clients from https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
     public void Send(string data)
     {
         // Invoke a method on the calling client
         Caller.addMessage(data);

         // Similar to above, the more verbose way
         Clients[Context.ConnectionId].addMessage(data);
     }
}
```